# How to copy folder itself with project.copy in gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy

Copying folder like this only copies the contents of source to target directory. How do I copy the folder itself to target directory?

```
project.copy {
    from "$source"
    into "$targetDirectory"
}
```

For example if

```
def source = "d:\\my\\docs" // containing files and subfolders
def targetDirectory = "d:\\destination"
```

and

```sh
> ls d:\my\docs
file1.txt
file2.xyz
subfolder/
...
```

then `project.copy` in first snippet will result in

```sh
> ls d:\destination
file1.txt
file2.xyz
subfolder/
```

Expected result is that docs folder itself is copied over, not just its contents.

```sh
> ls d:\destination
docs/
```

Because I don't know the paths already, one way is to get name from source

```
def src = new File("$source")
project.copy {
  from src
  if (source.isDirectory())
    into "$targetDirectory\\$src.name" //src.name == "docs"
  else
    into "$targetDirectory"
}
```

Is there a better way to do this with `project.copy` which works for both files and directories?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
project.copy {
   from 'd:/my'
   include 'docs/**' 
   into targetDirectory
}
```

Or perhaps

```
project.mkdir "$targetDirectory/docs" 
project.copy {
   from 'd:/my/docs'
   into "$targetDirectory/docs" 
}
```

The second option will likely be quicker if there's lots of other excluded files/directories under d:/my (since gradle will list all files/directories and test them against the "include" criteria)

Comment: I don't know the `$source` path beforehand. It could even be a file. Therefore I still have to get the `docs/` folder name with `new File('d:/my/docs').name`. Essentially you are doing exactly same in your second snippet as I did. First snippet looks like a nice alternative and can be reached using `new File('d:/my/docs').parent`. But it will be more slower if source was a network resource. What will happen if source was a file?